# In deep learning what's difference between two 3*3 convolution filters and one 5*5 convolution filters?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

For example, as to the `famous AlexNet architecutre`  [(original paper)](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf), what's the difference of using `two 3*3  convolution filters` between using `one 5*5 convolution filter` ?

The `two 3*3  convolution filters` and `one 5*5 convolution filter` have been highlighted by `red rectangle` in the below image.

[image: https://medium.com/@smallfishbigsea/a-walk-through-of-alexnet-6cbd137a5637]

[image]

What about use another `5*5 convolution filter` to supersede the `two 3*3  convolution filters`, or  vice verse?

Comment: two filters with non-linearity between can introduce more complex features than one filter...

Comment: Can you give any reference or paper about that ?

Comment: I suggest you to take the CS231n Stanford course. Specifically,  look at this note of this course: http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/
At the paragraph "Prefer a stack of small filter CONV to one large receptive field CONV layer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found from paper `<<Very Deep Convolutional Networks for Large-Scale Image Recognition>>`.

> Rather than using relatively large receptive fields in the first conv. layers (e.g. 11×11with stride 4 in (Krizhevsky et al., 2012), or 7×7 with stride 2 in (Zeiler & Fergus, 2013; Sermanet et al., 2014)), we use very small 3 × 3 receptive fields throughout the whole net, which are convolved with the input at every pixel (with stride 1). It is easy to see that a stack of two 3×3 conv.layers (without spatial poolingin between) has an effective receptive field of 5×5; three such layers have a 7 × 7 effective receptive field.

1. two 3*3 convolution filter is equivalent to one 5*5 convolution filter.
2. two 3*3 convolution filter will have less parameters than one 5*5 convolution filter.
3. two 3*3 convolution filter will make network more deep and extract more complex features than one 5*5 convolution filter.

paper:https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf

Answer (score 2):

*If you still have some doubt, hope this one helps.*

If you stack two 3x3 conv layers, it eventually gets a receptive field of 5 (same as one 5x5 conv layer) with respect to the input. However, the advantage of using a smaller conv layer like 3x3 is **it needs less parameter** (you can do the parameter calculation of two 3x3 layers and one 5x5 layer --> like 2*(3*3) = 18 and 1*(5*5) = 25 assuming 1 channel). Also, **two conv layer gets more non-linearity in between** than one 5x5 layer, so it has **got more discriminative power**.
For the receptive field part, I hope this paper of mine helps you to visualize (BTW it's the answer sheet from my exam):
[image: Receptive Field Visualization]